# Equivalence Classes Output

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I understand that an equivalence relation is a set that is reflexsive, symmetric, and transitive. I don't quite understand equivalence classes though.

For example:
What would the equivalence class be of the equivalence relation `{(0.0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}` if the (original?) set is `{0,1,2,3}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an equivalence relation on the set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ which is given by 
$$R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(1,3),(1,6),(6,1),(6,3),(3,1),(3,6),(2,4),(4,2)\}.$$
You can verify that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $S$.  Now, we define an equivalence class of $s\in S$ as
$$[s]=\{x\in S : x\ R\ s\}$$
So, what elements in $S$ are related to $6?$  They are $\{1,3,6\}.$  Using above notation we have
$$[6]=\{1,3,6\}$$
The set $\{1,3,6\}$ is called an equivalence class of $6$.  I'll leave the rest to you to see if you can find all the other equivalence classes.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence relation is a set of pairs of equivalent things.  In your example each element is equivalent to only itself so the equivalence classes are $\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}$.  If you add $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ (you need both pairs to have symmetry) to your equivalence relation then you'll have classes $\{0,1\},\{2\},\{3\}$.  Generally your initial set will break up into a disjoint union of equivalence classes whenever you have an equivalence relation.

Comment: So if I have a set `{(0.0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3)}` the equivalence class would be `{{0},{1,2},{3}}`?

Comment: that's right. @jnh has a good example for you above to look at